# How to draw function returning elements of an array using gadfly

Tags: function, drawing, julia, gadfly

Hello i am trying to draw a function with Gadfly using Julia.
I have no problem with function like this:

```
function F(x)
   return x+5
end
```

I use `plot(F,1,10)` and it works.
Unfortunately for this function which is returning elements of an array it doesn't work:

```
function F(x)
   return myArray[x]
end
```

I would be grateful for telling me where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an Index-Value plot of `myArray` elements I think the correct usage is:

`plot(y=myArray,x=1:10)`

and if you want to create a piecewise continuous plot, then declaration of `f(x)` should be something like this:

```
function F(x::Float64)
   global myArray
   return myArray[floor(Int,x)] # or myArray[round(Int,x)] or myArray[ceil(Int,x)]
end
```

Comment: Thanks @JobJob that reminded me, here `x=1:10` is more effective than `collect(1:10)`